# MySQL YEAR(4) and PHP DateTime not playing nice

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have a very rough script for the monotonous task of populating one of my database tables with teams attending different events every year. But it would be a lot nicer if I didn't have to go back and correct the year in the database every time.

I have a table of yearly events that gets queried, which in turn allows the script to fetch the list of teams for that event. The year is set using the following:

```
$year = date('Y');
```

For each team-event-year combination the following query fires:

```
INSERT INTO attendance (`team`,`event`,`year`) VALUES ('$team','$event','$year');
```

Everything looks fine (to my eye), but the year keeps returning as `0000` in the database even though the script prints `2012` when debugging.

My code is as follows:

```
// from shared parent script

$year = (date('m') < 9) ? date('Y') : date('Y')+1;

// attendance.php - file with code in question

<?php
header("Refresh: 43200;"); // refresh every 12 hours
ob_start();

echo "<p>Filling event rosters for the {$year} season.</p>"; ob_flush(); flush();

function getTeamList($event) {
    echo "<h3>Event '{$event}':</h3>"; ob_flush(); flush();

    echo "Removing old entries... "; ob_flush(); flush();
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM attendance WHERE event='$event' AND year='$year'");

    echo "Loading list from FIRST TIMS... "; ob_flush(); flush();
    $page =
file_get_contents("https://my.usfirst.org/myarea/index.lasso?page=teamlist&event_type=FRC&event=$event&year=$year&sort_teams=number");
    $page = explode('<td nowrap>',$page);
    $page = implode('<td>',array_slice($page,'1'));
    if ($event == 'CMP') {
        $page2 =
file_get_contents("https://my.usfirst.org/myarea/index.lasso?page=teamlist&event_type=FRC&event=$event&year=$year&sort_teams=number&skip_teams=250");
        $page2 = explode('<td nowrap>',$page2);
        $page2 = implode('<td>',array_slice($page2,'1'));
        $page = '<html><body><center><table>
<tr>
<td>'.$page.' <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <td>'.$page2;
    }
    $timsList = new DOMDocument;
    $timsList->loadHTML($page);
    $listings = $timsList->getElementsByTagName('a');

    echo "Adding all current entries... "; ob_flush(); flush();
    foreach ($listings as $listing) {
        if (is_numeric($listing->nodeValue)) {
            $team = $listing->nodeValue;
            $query = "INSERT INTO attendance (`team`,`event`,`year`) VALUES ('$team','$event','$year')";    // Build SQL query for events
            mysql_query($query);
        }
    }
    echo "Done."; ob_flush(); flush();
    if ($event == 'CMP') {
        $div = array('archimedes','curie','galileo','newton');
        foreach ($div as $division) {
            mysql_query("DELETE FROM attendance WHERE event='$division' AND year='$year'");
            $page =
file_get_contents("https://my.usfirst.org/myarea/index.lasso?page=teamlist&event_type=FRC&event=$event&division=$division&year=$year&sort=teamnum");
            $page = explode('<td nowrap>',$page);
            $page = implode('<td>',array_slice($page,'1'));
            $timsList = new DOMDocument;
            @$timsList->loadHTML($page);
            $listings = $timsList->getElementsByTagName('a');
            foreach ($listings as $listing) {
                if (is_numeric($listing->nodeValue)) {
                    $team = $listing->nodeValue;
                    $query  = "INSERT INTO attendance (`team`,`event`,`year`) VALUES ('$team','$division','$year')";    // Build SQL Query
for Divisions
                    mysql_query($query);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


if (isset($_GET["event"])) {
    $event = strtoupper(mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["event"]));
    mysql_select_db("frc");
    getTeamList($event);
} else {
    mysql_select_db("frc_{$year}scouting");
    $events = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM event WHERE event.start >= NOW()") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("frc");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($events)) {
        $event = $row['id'];
        getTeamList($event);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: what are the field type in database table.?

Comment: I should note, the year is not always the current year… I just displayed it in the question as such because the error occurs either way.

Comment: @DipeshParmar `team` is `INT(11)`, `event` is `VARCHAR(16)`, and `year` is `YEAR(4)`

Comment: try to add $year without quote because quote needs only when u insert string data into database.

Comment: or try to rename year field because some words are reserved for mysql..i was through same problem and changing name solve it

Comment: changing field name, adding removing quotes, and changing php variable type do not work

Comment: Actual code too long for this post, but if you are interested: [full code](http://pastebin.com/sbdPdEj6)

Comment: updated my awnser. You forgot global.

Comment: @qsheets get familiar with clicking the edit button :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the datatype of the year field in MYSQL? If its set as datetime field, then your date is not valid and it will return 0000 for the year. (Invalid dates are stored as 0000-00-00 00:00:00 in mysql datetime)

You could alter the database field to require an INT to make it work. Another option is to send in the year as $year.'-01-01 01:01:01' to store it as the januari first of the date. But considering thats a bogus year, why store the extra data? Just use INT.

UPDATE:

The code you show is correct. Nothing wrong with it. There must be something going on in the code you are not showing, or you are thinking you set everything like you said but havent.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(...);

$team = 10;
$event = 'Testing';
$year = date('Y');
$query = "INSERT INTO attendance (`team`,`event`,`year`) VALUES ('$team','$event','$year')";

print $query;
$mysqli->query($query);
```

Works like a charm using the exact datetypes as you in mysql.

UPDATE 2:

You are using $year in a function, but didnt include global $year;

```
function getTeamList($event) {
    global $year;
    //....
}
```

Comment: The field type is [YEAR(4)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/year.html). And I really want to know how to make this work, not avoid the problem entirely using INT as YEAR could prove to be a space saver in the database (table has nearly 40,000 entries).

Comment: Thank you. Why is it always the simplest of things that drives us up the wall? :)

Comment: Because you expect that you are doing them correct automatically :)

Answer (score 1):

## Year only accepts 1901 - 2155

The [MySQL year type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/year.html) only accepts years within a specific range. If you insert an invalid value it's going to return zeros:

```
mysql> create database so;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> use so;
Database changed
mysql> create table example ( y year(4) );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.09 sec)

mysql> insert into example values (1234);
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.08 sec)

mysql> select * from example;
+------+
| y    |
+------+
| 0000 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into example values (2012);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.07 sec)

mysql> select * from example;
+------+
| y    |
+------+
| 0000 |
| 2012 |
+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Given that this is how MySQL acts - it is quite likely that the value being inserted is not a number, or not a number within this range.

Comment: I know the limitations of the datatype. What I'm trying to avoid is manually typing the date in as you did here.

Comment: What I'm saying is I know I could manually enter, say, "2014" every time which is no better than what I have now, but what I would like is for the the result of PHP's `date('Y')` (which *should* return a 4-digit year) to work in place of a manually entered year.

Comment: What I'm saying is there is no difference between using a number and using the result of `date('Y')` - i.e. you are not inserting the result of date('Y') into mysql because that _is_ a valid value - where's your code ;)?

Answer (score 0):

You can try ::

```
INSERT INTO 
attendance (`team`,`event`,`year`) 
VALUES  ('$team','$event',YEAR(CURRENT_DATE))
```

Answer (score 0):

If the type of the **year** field is integer, chage to:

```
INSERT INTO attendance (`team`,`event`,`year`) VALUES ('$team','$event',$year);
```